# Trocar banner conforme http_referer e limitar clicks neste banner

Tags: php

Código PHP para banner no qual necessito.

Que seja detectado a REFERER. "caso venha do site especificado" Mostra Banner X Caso contrato BANNER Y.

E necessito que tenha um setcookie + limites de click permitidos. (Dentro de 30min) por ex:

Para que não fique sendo repetido o banner depois que o usuário clicar uma única

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o http_referer da variavel global $_SERVER
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

Com isso você pode utilizar os cookies para fazer toda a sua lógica para limitar os clicks e os banners que já foram visualizados.

Caso não tenha conhecimento em cookie: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php